# ¿Es posible llamara a una funcion en un procedimiento almacenado?

Tags: mysql, sql, funciones, stored-procedure, plsql

estoy realizando unos modulos de un proyecto el cual involucra trabajar con procedimientos almacenados en MYSQL , en uno de ellos debido a un id que esta en otra tabla necesito validar si realmente existe me surgio la duda si dentro de un procedimiento almacenado se puede mandar a llamar una funcion, no se si sea la forma mas optima, o que otra opcion existe para no tener todo en un procedimiento almacenado ya que de momento cuando ya son muchas lineas de codigo es algo confuso.

Comment: Sí, se puede. De paso, encapsulas funcionalidades y las reusas a través de tu aplicación en capa de persistencia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sí, desde un procedimiento almacenado, disparador o evento puedes llamar a una función o a cualquier otro procedimiento. De hecho, deberías hacerlo para estructurar un poco el código y así no tengas procedimientos tan largos y difíciles de mantener.

Comment: Si desde un procedimiento almacenado, disparador o evento se puede llamar a una función o a cualquier otro procedimiento, ¿ cómo se hace ?.

Comment: Igual que desde fuera: `SELECT funcion();` o `CALL procedimiento();`